# Iteratively reweighted least squares : asymmetric weights

Tags: regression, robust, irls

For robust m-estimation, all the convergence results I'm aware of assume symmetric weights (eg: Huber function) in their formulation of the iterative reweighted least squares algorithm. Does the method apply to asymmetric weights, and does the corresponding convergence results hold?